# For $u,v,x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, let $T(u,v)(x)=x - \frac{\langle(u+v),x\rangle}{1+\langle u,v\rangle}(u+v)+2\langle u,x\rangle v$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-explanation

The function in question appears in lemma $6.3$ of Milnors characteristic classes. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ denote the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^m$

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be unit vectors with $u \neq -v$. Let $T(u,v)$ denote the unique rotation of $\mathbb{R}^m$ which carries vector $u$ to vector $v$ and leaves everything orthogonal to $u$ and $v$ fixed. Alternatively, $T(u,v)$ can be defined by:

$$T(u,v)(x)=x - \frac{\langle(u+v),x\rangle}{1+\langle u,v\rangle}(u+v)+2\langle u,x\rangle v$$

Can somebody help me understand why this formula above works? I'm having troubles understanding why this formula gives the desired rotation. Thank you.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. I changed $T(u,v)(x)=x - \frac{<(u+v),x>}{1+< u,v>}(u+v)+2<u,x> v$ to $$ T(u,v)(x)=x - \frac{\langle(u+v),x\rangle}{1+\langle u,v\rangle}(u+v)+2\langle u,x\rangle v $$ and and $<-,->$ to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle,$ and did some other emendations. You can google "latex symbols" in such cases.

Comment: If you're doing this kind of math, you ought to refer to a LaTeX manual when doing things like this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I found the book online. The missing hypothesis is that $u,v$ are unit vectors. I pasted the relevant paragraph into an answer

Comment: @WillJagy : Is your comment supposed to be a reply to one of mine? And if not, why did you ping me?

Comment: @MichaelHardy just that the vectors were actually required to be unit vectors; you were already involved with the content of the question as far as edits. Apparently the OP edited in "unit vectors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\|u+v\|^2=2(1+\langle u,v\rangle)$. If we write $\displaystyle w=\frac{u+v}{\|u+v\|}$, the given formula is

$$ R = \mathrm{Id}-2ww^T+2vu^T. $$

Where does this formula come from?

One clue is that $\mathrm{Id}-2ww^T$ is the Householder matrix for reflection across $w$'s orthogonal complement. Indeed, a good geometry exercise is that the product of two hyperplane reflections is a plane rotation by $2\theta$, in the plane spanned by the hyperplanes' two normals, where $\theta$ is the angle between the hyperplanes. One can argue it suffices to do this in 2D, and then it becomes a synthetic geometry exercise.

Note that $w$ is halfway between $u$ and $v$, so the angle $\angle uw$ is half the angle $\angle uv$. Therefore we may take the product of the two Householder reflections associated with $u,w$'s complements:

$$ (\mathrm{Id}-2ww^T)(\mathrm{Id}-2uu^T). $$

If you FOIL this out, then simplify with $w=u+v$, you get $R$ (exercise).

Answer (score 0):

Page 77 in Milnor and Stasheff. They are required to be unit vectors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** Using $A$ for the given linear map and assuming $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors.

1. If $x\perp u,v$ then $A(x)=x$.
2. $A(u)=v$.
3. $A$ preserves norm and inner product in the span of $u,v$.
4. Deduce that $A$ is an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: they really are unit vectors. the OP neglected to state this. I pasted the correct page into an answer.

Comment: Ah. Oops. I did indeed notice this when I typed it up, but I thought Milnor was just generalizing the word rotation or something >.<